# Join with column outside subquery

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t1.name as r_name, t1.values as r_values
FROM table as t1
JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(amount) as amount
    FROM database2.table
    WHERE ids IN (t1.values)
) as t2
WHERE t1.id = 20;
```

I get an error, that `t1.values` inside the subquery is unknown column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your query and take inne `where` to `join` condition:

```
SELECT t1.name as r_name, t1.values as r_values
FROM table as t1
JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(amount) as amount
    FROM database2.table
) as t2 ON t2.ids = t1.values
WHERE t1.id = 20;
```

Also, you don't use `amount` column, so what is the point of `join`?

Another issue, you don't have any `join` condition defined.

I think you need to read about `join`s in SQL first :)

Comment: I use amount column and have join conditions, i just simplified the query to focus on the problem.

Comment: @mr.work Ok, but this way the query is very wrong and it's hard to guess what you want without such basic information and correct query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to join `database2.table` to your `t1` based on `t1.values` list.
I added group by IDs in `t2` since your using aggregation function. Then, not sure what's the purpose of your `sum(amount)`

```
SELECT t1.name as r_name, t1.values as r_values
FROM table as t1
JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(amount) as amount, ids
    FROM database2.table
    GROUP BY ids
) as t2 on t2.ids IN (t1.values)
WHERE t1.id = 20;
```